# How to add single quote after specific word using sed?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I am trying to write a script to add a single quote after a "GOOD" word . 
For example, I have file1 :

`//WER  GOOD=ONE
//WER1 GOOD=TWO2
//PR1  GOOD=THR45
...`

Desired change is to add single quotes :

`//WER  GOOD='ONE'
//WER1 GOOD='TWO2'
//PR1  GOOD='THR45'
...`

This is the script which I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

for item in `grep "GOOD" file1 | cut -f2 -d '='`

do

sed -i 's/$item/`\$item/`\/g' file1

done
```

Thank you for the help in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
sed "s/\(.*=\)\(.*\)/\1'\2'/"  Input_file
```

OR as per OP's comment to remove empty line use:

```
sed "s/\(.*=\)\(.*\)/\1'\2'/;/^$/d"  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** following is only for explanation purposes.

```
sed "              ##Starting sed command from here.
s/                 ##Using s to start substitution process from here.
\(.*=\)\(.*\)      ##Using sed buffer capability to store matched regex into memory, saving everything till = in 1st buffer and rest of line in 2nd memory buffer.
/\1'\2'            ##Now substituting 1st and 2nd memory buffers with \1'\2' as per OP need adding single quotes before = here.
/"  Input_file     ##Closing block for substitution, mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Please use `-i` option in above code in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

---

---

***2nd solution with `awk`:***

```
awk 'match($0,/=.*/){$0=substr($0,1,RSTART) "\047" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH) "\047"} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '
match($0,/=.*/){                                                     ##Using match function to mmatch everything from = to till end of line.
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART) "\047" substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH) "\047"   ##Creating value of $0 with sub-strings till value of RSTART and adding ' then sub-strings till end of line adding ' then as per OP need.
}                                                                    ##Where RSTART and RLENGTH are variables which will be SET once a TRUE matched regex is found.
1                                                                    ##1 will print edited/non-edited line.
' Input_file                                                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** In case you have only 2 fields in your Input_file then try more simpler in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} {$2="\047" $2 "\047"} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation of 3rd code:***  Use only for explanation purposes, for running please use above code itself.

```
awk '                    ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}        ##Setting FS and OFS values as = for all line for Input_file here.
{$2="\047" $2 "\047"}    ##Setting $2 value with adding a ' $2 and then ' as per OP need.
1                        ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: RavinderSingh13 - Thank you for the response! I have used the first sed command which you have provided, and it is adding the quote fine. However, after adding the quote, it is creating one more space below . So, I tried adding :space: to sed command as follows :   `sed "s/\(.*=\)\(.*\)[[:space:]]/\1'\2'/"  Input_file` . And it is still adding the space below. Do you know how I can fix it ?

Comment: @Sunny, When I tested this code with your provided samples it worked fine for me, not sure if your Input_file already have spaces? Or you have control M characters? Can you please run command `cat -v Input_file` to see if you have control M characters in it lemme know on it?

Comment: RavinderSingh13  When I did `cat -v Input_file` , it didn't show me any additional spaces. Anything I wanted to change in this file, it is adding the spaces below. For example, before in file1 , I changed `%%WER` into `//WER`  with adding [[:space:]] to sed command since without, it was adding spaces below.

Comment: @Sunny, I am really not sure about your previous command and my code is only focused on your shown samples, which worked fine for me. In case you are sending any other command's output to this new command then make sure that command itself shouldn't have spaces etc in it. I also added OR `sed` solution which removes a line with spaces(NULL line) lemme know how it goes now?

Comment: RavinderSingh13 Thank you for all the explanation! Definitely helpful! I just need to use sed command. The command is adding the quotes , however the ending single quote is finishing after some spaces. In the sed command you provided , is it possible to grep the word which comes after GOOD= , and substitute ? So, instead of giving `(.*\)`, is it possible to give the exact string which comes right after GOOD= ? Because when I do * , it is taking all the spaces as well.

Comment: @Sunny, All 3 commands work fine for me, can you please try other 2 awk commands too once?

Comment: @Sunny, could you please do lemme know if this helped you?